# System of equations - modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am asked to solve the following..... Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and suppose that $a,b,c,d,k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Consider the system $ax + by \equiv k$ mod $n$ and $cx+dy \equiv l$ mod $n$.
Let $D=ad-bc$. Show that if $hcf(D,n)=1$ then the system has a solution.

There were previous parts to the question, in which I showed $ax\equiv b$ mod $n$ has a solution iff $hcf(a,n)|b$.
But I have no idea how to proceed with this, I tried using the Euclidean algorithm to write $1=Ds+nr$ for $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}$ but it didn't seem to help much.
If any of you wonderful people could help me out, I will very much appreciate it.
Thank you.

Comment: $\gcd (D,n) = 1$ means the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} a& b\\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$$ is invertible modulo $n$. What is its inverse?

Comment: $\frac{1}{D} * \begin{pmatrix} d& -b\\ -c & a \end{pmatrix}$ I believe

Comment: What do you mean with $1/D$ there? (Remember, we are working with integers only.)

Comment: The multiplicative inverse of $D$ modulo $n$ (which exists since the hcf of D and n is 1)

Comment: Bingo! And, do you see how you get your solution of the system now?

Comment: Multiply by the vector (k,l) (column vector)

Comment: I suppose you mean the right thing there. You didn't say what to multiply by it, though.

Comment: Multiply \begin{pmatrix} de& -be\\ -ce & ae \end{pmatrix} with that vector where $e$ is the multiplicative inverse of $D$, is what I meant.

Comment: I thought so. Yes, that's it.