# system of modular equations question; condition for solutions

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

We were given the question;

Let $n$ be a natural number and $a,b,c,d,l,k$ be integers. Consider the system of equations;

$$ax + by \equiv  \text{mod}n $$
$$cx + dy \equiv \text{mod} n$$

and let $D=ad - bc$

Prove that the system only has solutions if $\text{hcf}(D,n) = 1$

I literally have no idea where to start with this, so any help would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/792081/system-of-equations-modular-arithmetic?rq=1

Comment: What's the inverse of \begin{pmatrix} 
  a   & b\\ 
  c & d 
\end{pmatrix} modulo $n$?

Comment: @Bacon $$\frac{1}{ad-bc} 
\[
 \begin{matrix}
  d & -b \\
  -c & a & 
 \end{matrix}
\] $$

Comment: Ok so what really do you mean when you write $D^{-1}$ - especially in the context of integers only..?